# Simplifying a circuit for nodal analysis

Tags: circuit-analysis, kirchhoffs-laws, nodal-analysis

I am trying to simplify/classify the following circuit:
[image: circuit diagram]

My textbook says it is a four-node circuit but I am coming up with 3 nodes. Doesn't the *"Ref."* dot and the *rightmost* dot combine into one node?

I also know, from the text, that \$v_{x} = v_{2}\$ and the only way that works is if the circuit elements are connected in parallel (i.e. have the same start/end node).

So my question is this: is this a 3-node circuit or a 4-node circuit and if it is a 3-node circuit, what would be the simplified drawing?

Comment: @kote I've no idea what they are teaching you, or what they are on while doing so, but [the graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w2Q6E.png) has three nodes. One of them can be selected as ground and would therefore be `known`. If you ground `Ref` then \$V_x=V_2\$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is your circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvVwnJ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Note that there are exactly three nodes.

> So my question is this: is this a 3-node circuit or a 4-node circuit
> and if it is a 3-node circuit, what would be the simplified drawing?

The simplified drawing is as shown above and the circuit has three nodes (if you are a graph theorist). It has only two unknown node voltages, though.

You know that \$i_a=\frac{v_1}{R_2}\$ and therefore that \$i_2=3\cdot\frac{v_1}{R_2}\$.

Using Norton to Thévenin conversions you can then get:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fT4tWk.png)</sup>

The above requires only the solution of a single equation to get \$v_1\$. And from there, the rest just falls out.

But the above goes above and beyond your question.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for making these diagrams. They helped a bunch.

Comment: @kote No problem. And I'm glad they did and that you let me know. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 nodes in the network. The reference node is chosen from among them. The 3i<sub>1</sub> current generator is in parallel with the 3 Ω resistor constituting a Norton circuit, it can be replaced by the Thévenin equivalent circuit.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Problem solved.